# How is ContactId determined in Visit object on Consumer Goods Cloud?

Tags: lookup, contact, fields, cloud, consumergoodscloud

I'm new to Consumer Goods Cloud and I would like to ask you about a doubt I haven't been able to discover.

I have not understand how is the "Contact" (ContactId) standard Lookup field updated on the Visit object. From what I've seen, this field is read-only and it cannot be modified. From the current layout I'm using, the Contact field appears, but I cannot edit or fill it.

How is this field updated?

Thank you in advance!